# Doing many returns in a function?

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to return the value of a function in order to echo it with another function< here's the code.

```
foreach($id as $sid){
$test .= '<li '.$class.'><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$post_title.'</a></li>';

return $test;
}
```

with the other function I echo the result of this function, when doing that it shows only the first result of the for loop. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `return` once. `Return` ends the execution of the current function. To `echo` the result, do this:

```
foreach($id as $sid){
    echo '<li '.$class.'><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$post_title.'</a></li>';
}
```

To only `return` once, put the return outside of the `for` loop:

```
foreach($id as $sid){
    $test .= '<li '.$class.'><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$post_title.'</a></li>';
}
return $test;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to move the `return` statement outside of the for loop.

```
foreach($id as $sid){
    $test .= '<li '.$class.'><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$post_title.'</a></li>';
}

return $test;
```

A [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

Answer (score 2):

Put your return outside the loop:

```
foreach($id as $sid){
  $test .= '<li '.$class.'><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$post_title.'</a></li>';
}
return $test;
```